# Является ли тип указателя наследником определенного базового типа

Tags: c++, указатели, наследование

Есть ли в C++ способ определить, является ли тип указателя наследником определенного базового типа?
Например:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(T *obj)
{
    if (Extends<Object>(obj))
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```

Comment: Это нужно на этапе компиляции или в рантайме? Уточните задачу.

Comment: по идее в рантайме, т.к. нужно чтобы в зависимости от типа выполнялся тот или иной кусок кода и при этом код всегда компилился. если тоже самое можно провернуть и на этапе компиляции, то вполне сойдет и такая схема.

Comment: Заверните <a href=http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast>`dynamic_cast<>`</a> в шаблон.

Comment: он работает только для полиморфичных типов, а мне надо для любых.. на самом деле нашел ответ.. std::is_base_of<BaseType, ChildType>::value

Comment: @РомаТюлин Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, оформить свой последний  комментарий как ответ (чтобы будущие читатели сразу увидели решение проблемы, и вопрос не висел в списке не отвеченных)? Просто скопируйте нужную из него часть в ответ и помедте отвеченным - это нормальная практика.

Answer (score 8):

В С++11 (в файле `type_traits`) появился шаблон класса `is_base_of`:

```
template< class Base, class Derived >
struct is_base_of;
```

В этом классе есть статический константный член типа `bool` с именем `value`. Он установлен в `true` если `Derived` является производным типом от `Base`(неважно, будь то `public`, `protected` или `private` наследование). И `false` в противном случае. Также следует заметить, что `value` установлен в `true`, если `Base` и `Derived` являются одним и тем же типом (не работает для фундаментальных типов и указателей).
Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : protected A {};
class D : private A {};
class F : public D {};
class Z {};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_base_of<A, B>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of<A, C>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of<A, D>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of<A, A>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of<A, F>::value << endl;
    cout << is_base_of<A, Z>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И получим вывод:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
```

В С++17 появился вспомогательный шаблон переменной:

```
template< class Base, class Derived >
inline constexpr bool is_base_of_v = is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value;
```

Он помогает избежать обращение к члену `value`. С помощью него можно писать так:

```
cout << is_base_of_v<A, B> << endl;
cout << is_base_of_v<A, C> << endl;
cout << is_base_of_v<A, D> << endl;
cout << is_base_of_v<A, A> << endl;
cout << is_base_of_v<A, F> << endl;
cout << is_base_of_v<A, Z> << endl;
```

И получим тот же вывод, что и ранее.
Более подробно можно узнать здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

---

В С++11 (в файле `type_traits`) появился шаблон класса `is_convertible`:

```
template< class From, class To >
struct is_convertible;
```

Он проверяет, может ли тип `From` быть неявно преобразован в тип `To`. В этом классе, как и в `is_base_of`, есть статический константный член `value` типа `bool`. Он установлен в `true`, если тип `From` может быть неявно преобразован в тип `To`, и в `false` в противном случае.
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : protected A {};
class D : private A {};

class X
{
public:
    operator A() { return a; }
private:
    A a;
};

class Y
{
public:
    explicit operator A() { return a; }
private:
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_convertible<A*, B*>::value << endl;
    cout << is_convertible<B*, A*>::value << endl;
    cout << is_convertible<C*, A*>::value << endl;
    cout << is_convertible<D*, A*>::value << endl;
    cout << is_convertible<X, A>::value << endl;
    cout << is_convertible<Y, A>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И вывод:

```
false
true
false
false
true
false
```

Немого пояснений.
`is_convertible<A*, B*>::value` даёт `false`, потому что невное нисходящее преобразование запрещено в С++.
`is_convertible<B*, A*>::value` даёт `true`, потому что неявное восходящее преобразование разрешено только для открытого наследования. По этой причине  `is_convertible<C*, A*>::value` и `is_convertible<D*, A*>::value` дают `false`.
`is_convertible<X, A>::value` даёт `true`, потому что класс `X` имеет оператор преобразования в `A`, который может вызываться неявно. Он не обьявлен как `explicit`.
`is_convertible<Y, A>::value` даёт `false`, потому что его оператор преобразования в `A` обьявлен как `explicit`, и не может быть вызван неявно.
В С++17 появился вспомогательный шаблон переменной:

```
template< class From, class To >
inline constexpr bool is_convertible_v = is_convertible<From, To>::value;
```

Он помогает избежать обращение к члену `value`. С помощью него можно писать так:

```
cout << is_convertible_v<A*, B*> << endl;
cout << is_convertible_v<B*, A*> << endl;
cout << is_convertible_v<C*, A*> << endl;
cout << is_convertible_v<D*, A*> << endl;
cout << is_convertible_v<X, A> << endl;
cout << is_convertible_v<Y, A> << endl;
```

Получим тот же вывод, что и ранее.
Более подробно здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible

---

В С++20 должен появиться концепт `derived_from` в файле `concepts`:

```
template< class Derived, class Base >
concept derived_from =
  std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived> &&
  std::is_convertible_v<const volatile Derived*, const volatile Base*>;
```

Более подробно здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from